# How can I prevent saxon from escaping systemId in Results produced by xsl:result-document

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am producing a document using `<xsl:result-document href="{$uri}"> ...` where $uri contains some non-ASCII characters.  I've registered an OutputURIResolver, and when it receives the href in its resolve(href, base) method, the href has been uri-escaped.  Can I prevent that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can prevent this. I'm not sure exactly why it's being done, but the interface for OutputURIResolver does say that the arguments are URIs, and you can't have unescaped non-ASCII characters in a URI.

Comment: Hm yes. I can see why this might happen.  Zealous application of "standards," I call it :)  Although it might have been *truly* standards compliant to generate an error instead of trying to magically fix things up.